# Turtlebot 2D Nav Goal not working

Tags: ros, navigation, turtlebot, ros-fuerte, 2d-nav-goal

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am running the turtlebot navigation demo in fuerte and 12.04 Precise.  Everything works fine up until I try and set a nav goal in rviz, then nothing happens.  The console output says that a goal is being set, but the turtlebot does not move and no messages are sent on move_base_simple/goal.  I am using the versions of rviz and the demos directly from the repositories with no modifications.  Does anyone know why this might be happening?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/43736/turtlebot-2d-nav-goal-not-working/) by [Aroarus](https://answers.ros.org/users/990/aroarus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 122 on 2012-09-12

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It sounds like you don't have the proper goal topic configured in rviz.

In particular, you should set the 2D Nav Toal topic to /move_base_simple/goal in the Tool Properties window.

Take a look at http://ros.org/wiki/navigation/Tutorials/Using%20rviz%20with%20the%20Navigation%20Stack

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2012-09-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Aroarus](https://answers.ros.org/users/990/aroarus/) on 2012-09-13**:
Unfortunately, I have that set properly already in rviz.  When using rostopic echo to listen to the "move_base_simple/goal" topic however, nothing gets sent when I use the "2D Nav Goal" button in RViz.  Also nothing gets sent when I hit the "2D Pose Estimate" button and listen to "initialpose"

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2012-09-13**:
Are you running ROS over a network? Which machine are you running 'rostopic echo' on?

**Comment by [Aroarus](https://answers.ros.org/users/990/aroarus/) on 2012-09-17**:
I am running ROS between two computers over my lab wireless network.  I have tried running rostopic echo on both the workstation and the mobile computer, with the same result.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2012-09-17**:
I would walk through the network setup and make sure everything there is in order: http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/NetworkSetup

**Comment by [Devasena Inupakutika](https://answers.ros.org/users/4122/devasena-inupakutika/) on 2013-03-23**:
Have you checked your frames.pdf file ? You can check the transforms that are published. Please type below command on another terminal and frames.pdf file will be generated: rosrun tf view_frames

**Comment by [Devasena Inupakutika](https://answers.ros.org/users/4122/devasena-inupakutika/) on 2013-03-23**:
You should get a tree like the following link --> /map -> /odom -> base_link -> openni_camera. If anyone link is missing, turtlebot won't move and you get warning that particular link is not found. Hope this helps !!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Check turtlebot_teleop keyboard_teleop is  running on  your  computer. I had same problem with you but when i killed console controler node, turtlebot moved to the goal.

---

Originally posted by [Castlespike](https://answers.ros.org/users/22778/castlespike/) with karma: 11 on 2015-06-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1